# Alert While moving to another page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have an application where people can take on line test , When the user moves to another page the page should alert like you may lost the details if u go out of the page...
I tried of `window.unload()` but what i need is it should show alert only when the user moves to another page

Ex : My Page id `test.php`
if user clicks next button for next question the page will redirect to `test.php?queNumber=2`
so when the redirection happens to test.php it should not show alert if it redirects to other page like about.php or help.php it should alert , How to achive this ???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign an event to all anchors in the page. And this event should check if anchor's href contain 'test.php' or not.

Try the following code:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
   var href = $(this).attr('href');
   if(href.indexOf('test.php') == -1) { //if href does not contain test.php
      event.preventDefault();
      alert('You are about to leave');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled client-side by Javascript.

The easiest is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) as you can do it really easily.

1. Add jQuery to your head - details on the jQuery page, linked.
2. In your HTML, add a class to any of the links that you want to alert the user, e.g.

   ```
   <a href=".." class="pop">Link Text</a>
   ```
3. Then add some Javascript along the lines of

   ```
   $().ready( function() {
       $('.pop').click( function(e) {
          if (! confirm('You are about to leave - are you sure')) {
              e.preventDefault();
              return false;
          } else {
              return true;
          }
       });
   });
   ```

Note: if you have too many links, or unknown links, you can reverse the logic to mark only those links you don't want to warn. so add the class to links for test.php, leave the rest without the marker class. Then check all links, and if they have the class, don't prompt.

Comment: i know this but i have more links more than 20 should i give all the same class name n do this.... Dont i have any other way???

Comment: Yes, you give them all the same class name - you want the same behaviour. Or go the other option or marking those that don't want to prompt. The alternative is to add "onclick" functionality in all the links which is a lot more painful that jQuery.

Comment: Actually - see Halil's. Not quite right (you only prevent default if the confirm is false, plus you need to check it's an internal link etc.) So a mixture of the two will get you there.